# "I will be here until 7pm."

Tags: grammaticality

I am having trouble trying understanding this sentence grammatically.

I'm not sure if it's an abbreviation a future continuous tense where the action of "staying" is implied or if it's even future continuous at all?

From as i understand, the rule of future continuous is:

> The future continuous refers to an unfinished action or event that
>   will be in progress at a time later than now.

The action in the sentence is referring to an unfinished action "here until 7pm" but there is no base form verb in the sentence to add "ing" to.

So i am wondering is this really future continuous and the base form verb is implied as below?

> I will be (staying) here until 7pm.

But then i don't feel this sentence feels right in the context of:

> If you need me i will be (staying) here until 7pm.

That doesn't feel right to me.

Is it more correct to say "I am here until 7pm."

Comment: Hi, and welcome to English Language & Usage. Thank you for quoting someone about future continuous. May we know the book or article that you are quoting, please?

Comment: You're overthinking it. This is not future continuous. (And if we're really strict, this is no future tense at all, because English does not have a future tense.)

Comment: @rajah9 I'm just quoting as it was said to me, unfortunately it's not from a book or  article.

Comment: {B} "I am here until 7 pm" is certainly acceptable. But (a) quite formal/clipped, so not used all that frequently, and (b) in my opinion, highly idiomatic (we don't say "I stay/work/socialise ... here until 7 pm", with a non-habitual, one-off sense. So some might claim this doesn't feel right.) // {C} "I will be staying here until 7pm" is certainly acceptable, and (with _I'll_) regularly used. Often when someone has asked about your plans. // {D} "I will / I'll be here until 7[pm]" is totally idiomatic and, I'd say, the most commonly used. Practised Anglophones would not feel uncomfortable ...

Comment: using it. {A} It may break a rule given in various rulebooks, but, unless said rulebooks contain many more pages than CGEL's 1800ish, they can't come close to covering every accepted usage, and are bound to give over-generalisations that will conflict with actual usage in various places. And yes, it may be a shortened form of  "I will be staying here until 7pm". Deletions abound in English.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, i'm not sure i understand that English has no future tense? Are you referring to simple future, future continuous or future perfect continuous?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for your explanation. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Bezzo ELU regulars have a consensus that 'tense' is best used for 'verb-forms showing inflexions for time reference', and there are only two of these in English: present simple, and past simple. All other periphrastic devices used to show time reference are 'constructions' rather than 'tenses'. So, for instance, 'will go', using an auxiliary (here, a modal) as well as the main verb _go_, is not an example of a  'future tense'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ohh, i didn't realise that as most grammar lesson websites i come across always say there's 12 tenses. 4 of which are future tense. Than you for clearing that up for me.

Comment: It will only really be cleared up when everyone agrees on the best way to analyse and name things. I can't see it ever happening. We can't agree here on single definitions for 'word', 'sentence' ....